# Errors while launching Webspher server

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, ear, websphere-7

Back to SO after a long time :-).
I have deployed an ear for our application in Websphere (using this server for the first time). When I started the server, am getting a lot of errors (am not sure if it has got something to do with the bean configurations in the code).

I have attached the errors with this post. Can you please shed some light on it ? Am I missing something? Do jars need to be placed explicitly in some location?
[Log 1](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6CE45610B49F9B52!156)
[Log 2](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6CE45610B49F9B52!158)

I have been breaking head with this for more than 2 days now. Did all the search in Google but no clue where to start or what exactly is going wrong.

(i) I am able to deploy ear successfully.

(ii) When I start the server, am getting all the errors which I attached in the logs.

(iii) I am able to launch the application successfully (Can see the login page), but when I login, I get a 'WebPage CAnnot be found'. Well I can see the url changing as '**siteminderagent/forms/login.fcc**'. This should be some kind of 3rd party authentication tool. I need to do some configuration for the same somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

First, WAS 7 is getting pretty old. For getting started with Websphere, if you can choose your version, use the current one. Second, read about the WAS class loaders because they may be a bit different than what you are familiar with from other app servers.

The error in log 1 looked like it may be associated with JPA. For JPA with WAS 7 IBM recommends installing a separate feature pack which provides Apache OpenJPA. If you still wanted/needed to use Hibernate there are instructions for how to configure an alternative JPA provider.

Comment: So since JPA is being used, I have the option of either upgrading server or download the feature pack?